# $\mathbb{Q}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is it true that $\mathbb{Q}$ is open (closed) in $\mathbb{R}$ with standart topology?Or it's neither open nor closed?.Since for any point $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ there is no neighborhoud $U(p) \subset \mathbb{Q}$ so it's not open.Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable union of points it's looks like closed, but countable union of closed subsets don't need to be closed.

Comment: Rationals are not closed. Closed subsets contain all limit points. Can you think about a sequence of rationals which is convergent, but not to a rational?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}$ is not closed, since $\bar{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{R}$, and sets are closed if and only if they equal their own closure.

It's not open either, since every open interval contains both rational and irrational numbers.